# Automatically detecting whether a process is running normally by listening to stdout for continuous stream of messages

Tags: command-line, mingw, msys

I have a chatty application that I'd like to automatically test post CI/CD build by leveraging the output stream as follows:

If the application is running normally it will continuously dump a few lines of text per second to the console. If the build is missing a library and has displayed an error dialog or failed to start nothing will be written to the output stream. Even if message is printed it will not be continuous stream of text the application normally dumps out.

How can I automatically listen for continuous activity over say 30 seconds in order to decide whether the application is running normally or not.

On final detail. I am running in MINGW64/MSYS2 and do not have access to the full range of Linux command line tools.

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
watch -n 1 'myApplication'
```

Or should I `tee` the output of `myApplication` to a file and watch the file? I'd like to determine if the file size does not grow.